# How to import a closure from groovy to java?

Tags: java, groovy, closures, embedded-language

I'm trying to extract a closure from a groovy script. I define the closure as

```
def printMe = {str ->println str}
```

in my groovy file, and then try to use it by grabbing it from the binding as follows:

```
GroovyScriptEngine gse = new GroovyScriptEngine(new String[] { "scripts" });
Binding binding = new Binding();
gse.run("test.groovy", binding);
Closure cls = (Closure) binding.getVariable("printMe");
cls.call("foo");
```

But I get the following error when I run this.

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: 
    printMe for class: groovy.lang.Binding
    at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:55)
    at GroovyTry.main(GroovyTry.java:19)
```

Is there a way to grab a closure (or a plain method) from a groovy script?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What happens if you omit the `def` from your closure declaration?

```
printMe = { str -> println str }
```

By using def, I think the `printMe` variable becomes local to the script, rather than going in the Binding

Read more about [Scoping and the Semantics of "def"](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Scoping+and+the+Semantics+of+%22def%22)